# How to Find and Replace the Enter character?

Tags: visual-c++, char

How to Find and Replace the 'Enter' characters in the text file? Here is my code:

```
string searchString( "\r" );   // <------- how to look for ENTER chars?
string replaceString( "XXXX" );

assert( searchString != replaceString );

string::size_type pos = 0, pos3 =0;

while ( (pos = test.find(searchString, pos)) != string::npos ) {
    test.replace( pos, searchString.size(), replaceString );
            pos++; }
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: george, it somehow does not detect the Enter character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search `\r\n` for Windows format, `\n` for Linux/Unix format, `\r` for Mac format in text files.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your goals are.

If you want all newline characters to look the same, [you'd better be thorough](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/01/the-great-newline-schism.html).  According to the linked article, there are at least five patterns to look for:

- Windows (CR LF)
- Mac (CR)
- Unix (LF)
- Unicode Line Separator
- Unicode Paragraph Separator

I'd think looking for byte patterns (by treating it as a binary file rather than a text file) would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

The enter character is "\n", but in Windows, "\r\n", old Mac "\r".
For mixed newlines: regexp /(?<[^\r\n])(?:\r|\n|\r\n)(?=[^\r\n])/

Comment: RegEx? Where did the OP ask for that?

Comment: @George, you can use RegEx to find and replace.  OP did ask for find and replace.